# CMD: tryin to get a substring out a file using regex

Tags: regex, batch-file, cmd

I've got a script that uses `wget` to download certain file, `test.txt`, which containts:

> {"orderNumber": "1476628690_2WOSU1OR"}<

I only want the `ordernumber` itself, without all the text around it. I've googled it and found many answers for similar problems with `findstr` and forloops, but since I'm a complete novice in batch, I didn't understand much of it.

Is there a function that accepts a regex and an input file and changes the file into something else?

Comment: sorry, no REGEX in batch. Just `findstr` has a very reduced subset of REGEX support, but just to search in a string; no extraction is possible with `findstr`. To get a substring, use `for` with fitting `tokens` and `delims`. See `for /?` for details.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you want to re-write the file to only contain the order number **and remove all other text?**

Are there any other characters before or after this that might be ont he line or is the line always just the characters **{"orderNumber": "1476628690_2WOSU1OR"}<**

Assuming that you want to re-write the entire file to contain only the order number and that the stand along line is always formatted as your example input was Then the following is sound:

At Command Line:

```
for /f tokens^=4^ delims^=^"  %A IN ('type "C:\Admin\Stack_Exchange\40071522\test.txt" ^| FIND /I "OrderNumber" ') DO @( Echo.%~A>"C:\Admin\Stack_Exchange\40071522\test.txt"&exit /b)
```

I'll assume in reality you are probably calling a batch file "Reorder.cmd" and putting the path to the file as the only argument.

In a Batch File:

```
REM Script: Reorder.cmd
FOR /F Tokens^=4^ Delims^=^"  %%A IN ('Type "%*" ^| FIND /I "OrderNumber" ') DO (
 Echo.%%~A>"%*"
 GOTO :EOF
)
```

Resulting text File Contents:

```
1476628690_2WOSU1OR
```

Comment: Would be cleaner to just use the colon and curly braces as the delimiters. The quotes surrounding can always be removed by using the tilde when expanding the FOR variable.

Comment: I considered that at the outset, and that's why I asked for very specific questions here to see if I should change things.<p>Only if I can be sure there are no other spaces, or don't use the space as a delimiter, both of which mean more stripping off of characters, I like to avoid it if it's not necessary because the code is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Since the txt file is in the same folder as my .cmd script i made it:
for /f tokens^=4^ delims^=^"  %A IN ('type "test.txt" ^| FIND /I "OrderNumber" ') DO @( Echo.%~A>"test.txt"&exit /b)

but it doesnt delete the rest. Ive put it in a script on its own: GetNumber.cmd and have run it a few times but the txt file says the same.

Answer (score 0):

I can't respond to your comment because I only have 41 points (need 50 apparently) So I have to post my comment as another answer.

> Since the txt file is in the same folder as my .cmd script i made it:
>   for /f tokens^=4^ delims^=^" %A IN ('type "test.txt" ^| FIND /I
>   "OrderNumber" ') DO @( Echo.%~A>"test.txt"&exit /b)
>
> but it doesnt delete the rest. Ive put it in a script on its own:
>   GetNumber.cmd and have run it a few times but the txt file says the
>   same.

I can assure you the code works and is tested in Windows 7, 2008 R2 and 2012 R2, however I have used the same sort of code as long ago as Windows 2000 without a hitch.

Based off your response I see you have some confusion about how the code works and where it should be run, I'm not sure if I can clarify that for you below, or if it would be easier to just try to be more explicit and so I do both below.

Why your attempts are not working:

The first code you mention being in a .cmd file would not run correctly within a batch file (Windows CMD requires extra escaping within a batch/CMD file which would not work in a cmd prompt).

This code was intended to be run by pasting into the CMD prompt directly, and required you to have used the full path or to first "CD" into the same folder

Below are several ways of doing the same thing, I try to be more explicit about how to use them to accomplish your goal, and what info you need to provide.

### To try this in the CMD Prompt (Not a .bat/.cmd file) replace the [YOUR_PATH] Items here and then paste directly into a CMD prompt.

```
for /f tokens^=4^ delims^=^" %A IN ('type "[YOUR_PATH]\test.txt" ^| FIND /I "OrderNumber" ') DO @( Echo.%~A>"[YOUR_PATH]\test.txt"&exit /b)
```

### You seem to want to hard code the file and call from a batch file, here I re-write the "GetNumber.cmd" you mentioned to be more to your liking.  Again, please specify the full path in the variable inside the cmd file otherwise it will not work

```
REM Script: GetNumber.cmd
SET "FullPathAndFileName=[YOUR_PATH]\test.txt"
FOR /F Tokens^=4^ Delims^=^"  %%A IN ('Type "%FullPathAndFileName%" ^| FIND /I "OrderNumber" ') DO (
 Echo.%%~A>"%FullPathAndFileName%"
 GOTO :EOF
)
```

### In the original I offtered you this version of the CMD which will work with any file location -- Just drag and drop the file onto the .cmd file to test and it will work. -- Or you can also call the batch file from the CMD and put the full path to the file as an argument as so: Reorder.cmd [YOUR_PATH]\test.txt

```
REM Script: Reorder.cmd
FOR /F Tokens^=4^ Delims^=^"  %%A IN ('Type "%*" ^| FIND /I "OrderNumber" ') DO (
 Echo.%%~A>"%*"
 GOTO :EOF
)
```

### Here are the before and after contents of my test file:

### Before:

```
Hello there" Some stuff here"
"
""
{"orderNumber": "1476628690_2WOSU1OR"}<
more stuff here
the end
C:\Admin\Stack_Exchange\40071522
```

### After:

```
1476628690_2WOSU1OR
```